# Going up a directory in Nautilus' location bar

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

I am trying to go up a directory in Nautilus' location bar. For example, I start here:

[image: mitch > Dropbox > dev > snippets]

I then give focus to the location bar, type `..` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, but it brings me to the first folder in the breadcrumb:

[image: mitch]

The folder it uses seems to vary depending on where I am in the file system. It makes using the dialog extremely painful. Is there a way to configure this behaviour so that it behaves like `cd ..`?

Comment: Don't use Nautilus myself, but have you tried typing `..`?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69435/how-to-get-up-parent-button-in-nautilus-without-using-breadcrumbs

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I have - it's written in my question. Thanks for the link. Alt + Up will have to do. If you answer with that (I'm only interested in keyboard shortcuts), I can accept it.

Comment: Ha! Turns out this shortcut is used on Windows, too. That makes it much more useful. :) Perhaps worth noting in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69435/how-to-get-up-parent-button-in-nautilus-without-using-breadcrumbs) you can type <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd> to go up a level.

You can also use the menu item `Go->Open Parent`.